# Find max values with condition

Tags: excel

I have this data:

```
Animal    Age   Animal (Unique) 
Dog        4    Dog
Dog        3    Cat
Cat        10   Bird
Bird       1   
Cat        2
Bird       3
Cat        2
Dog        12
```

I want to find the max values, so I tried this:

```
Animal    Age   Animal (Unique) Max_age
Dog        4    Dog             MAX(IF(A:A=C2,B:B))
Dog        3    Cat             MAX(IF(A:A=C3,B:B))
Cat        10   Bird            MAX(IF(A:A=C4,B:B))
Bird       1   
Cat        2
Bird       3
Cat        2
Dog        12
```

But I have an error and I dont know why.

Comment: Does your version of Excel not support MAXIFS?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Scott: "There is a problem with this formula..." . BigBen: how can i see that? Excel recommends me to use "max" and "if"

Comment: Did you forget the closing paranthesis?

Comment: Also do you use `;` instead of `,` as the delimiter?

Comment: But to @BigBen comment, if you have Office 365 or 2019 or later, then use MAXIFS instead.  MAX(IF()) is the old way.

Comment: @ScottCraner now I am using ";" and it gives me values ​​0

Comment: What version are you using?  Anything before Office 365 you need to confirm with Ctrl-Shift-Enter when exiting edit mode.

Comment: @ScottCraner I have the office 2021 version, I don't know why that happens. Now I can run the action 1 time, but when I reopen the .xlsx file I get "_xlfn"

Comment: if you are using 2021 switch to MAXIFS() instead: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/maxifs-function-dfd611e6-da2c-488a-919b-9b6376b28883

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following approach that works for Excel 2021 in cell `E2` via `MAXISF` suggested in the comments. Provided here the details on how to do it:

```
=MAXIFS(B2:B9,A2:A9,UNIQUE(A2:A9))
```

The formula returns an array, so there is no need to extend the formula down.

[image: sample excel file]

This is a disclaimer from Microsoft about [MAXIFS](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/maxifs-function-dfd611e6-da2c-488a-919b-9b6376b28883):

> Excel for Microsoft 365, Excel for Microsoft 365, for Mac Excel, for the
> web Excel 2021, **Excel 2021**, for Mac Excel 2019, Excel 2019 for Mac.
> This feature is available on Windows or Mac if you have Office 2019,
> or if you have a Microsoft 365 subscription. If you are a Microsoft
> 365 subscriber, make sure you have the latest version of Office.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with your formula itself. It works fine.

There IS a problem though. The `_xlfn` prefix tells you EXACTLY what the problem is.
When you use a function your version allows, save the spreadsheet, then open it on an earlier version that does not have that function, Excel loads the spreadsheet, including the right answer from the time it was saved, but realizes the function is not available so it cannot recalculate it. It immediately adds `_xlfn` to the function name and will not further attempt to calculate it. This is the ONLY reason it adds the `_xlfn`, there is NO other reason. If you force it to recalculate, it wipes out the result it brought in from the last time the file was saved and gives you an error from then on.

So either you are not the one creating it, just opening it and cannot due to having too early a version which isn't the case as you have the 2021 version, or you are creating it in that version, in which it works fine, but later opening it, or a user of yours is later opening it, and the version being used is too early so this happens.

It cannot be the `IF` since that's been there since the first edition. `MAX` on the other hand... it's only been there since Excel 2007 (Excel 2011 for the Mac world). So if using, say, Excel 2003 or even Excel 97 (both fine versions but I wouldn't trade for them), you will see this.

By the way, `_xlfn` breaks down as "xl" = Excel, and "fn" = function. Pretty on point as an abbreviation. MS Office programs in general use this labelling method for this kind of thing (so for Field Codes with the same issue in Word, and so on).

In no way is it a matter of needing to use "array formula entry" (our old, old friend `Ctrl-Shift-Enter`). That would simply work (if it wasn't actually needed to begin with), not work (if it weren't a good formula to begin with), or look like it's working but it isn't really (a terrible concern since so many spreadsheets involve money in one way or another!), depending upon the exact functions and the exact data/usage of the function. The thing you are getting is NOT ever triggered by using `Ctrl-Shift-Enter` or not using it, nor by a version supporting modern array usage creating a file that is later opened in an earlier version.

I am not versed in Excel versions for other platforms, as in the phone version or the internet browser version. However, I have read many times of those not supporting some very surprising function or another. So perhaps you are opening the file on such a platform and the version used is either not mature enough to have caught up or will never have the function. Hard to picture with just `IF` and `MAX` but possible.

Whichever function the `_xlfn` is connected to is your problem. Not that that matters I guess since it has to be `MAX` and there are no products from MS or others that add later functions into older versions so it cannot be fixed anyway.

You need to find a "workaround" that does not use the offending function.

One last thing:  it IS that function, not the formula as a whole. The version of Excel you see the problem in simply doesn't have the function in it. It is not a matter of a combination of things just not going well together.